# Rails model create action shows id as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 app where in a Model I'm creating a `Comment` record.

I then want to email the new `Comment`.

This is my model code:

```
  before_create :worequest_comment

  protected
  def worequest_comment
    if self.workorder.worequest_id != nil
      if self.internal_only == false
        newcomment = Comment.create({:worequest_id => self.workorder.worequest_id, :comments => self.log_desc, :status_date => DateTime.now, :user_id => self.employee.user_id})
        CommentMailer.comment_email(newcomment).deliver if self.workorder.worequest.employee_id != nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But, `newcomment` variable doesn't show the comment.id

See this:

[image]

Thank for your help!

Comment: This happens probably because `newcomment` is not `valid?`, try using `Comment.create!` (exclamation point `!` after the `create`) to raise an error if the object is not valid when you save it and you will see which attribute(s) is not respecting the validates you defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the CommentMailer to the Comment model:

```
  after_create :comment_email

  protected
  def comment_email
    if !self.worequest.employee_id.nil?
      if Worequest.find(self.worequest_id).employee_id != nil
        Comment2Mailer.comment2_email(self.id).deliver
      end
      if Worequest.find(self.worequest_id).r_send == true
        CommentMailer.comment_email(self.id).deliver
      end
      if self.statuscode_id != nil
        Worequest.find(self.worequest_id).update_attributes(:statuscode_id => self.statuscode_id)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are referring comment_id of object before saving object to db, since `before_create` execute in the context where record is not created/saved in the database.

Changing `before_create :worequest_comment` to `after_create :worequest_comment` should work